# How to check a word in an array for several values

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, indexof

My heading might be a bit confusing, sorry for that. Didn´t know what to say.

I have a working example which I tried to make shorter, but I didn´t know how.

```
function pigIt(str){
  let words = str.split(" ")
  let result = []
 for (let word of words) {
   
   if (word === "!"  ){
     result.push(word)
   }
     else if (word === "?"  ){
     result.push(word)
   }
     else if (word === "."  ){
     result.push(word)
   }
     else if (word === ","  ){
     result.push(word)
   }
   

   else if (word.indexOf("?") > -1){
  result.push(word.slice(1, word.length-1) + word[0] + "ay" +word[word.length-1])}
  else if (word.indexOf("!") > -1){
  result.push(word.slice(1, word.length-1) + word[0] + "ay" +word[word.length-1])}
  else if (word.indexOf(",") > -1){
  result.push(word.slice(1, word.length-1) + word[0] + "ay" +word[word.length-1])}
 else if (word.indexOf(".") > -1){
  result.push(word.slice(1, word.length-1) + word[0] + "ay" +word[word.length-1])}
 else result.push(word.slice(1,word.length) + word[0] + "ay")
 }
 return result.join(" ")
}


console.log(pigIt("Hello world")) // returns elloHay orldway
console.log(pigIt("Hello world !")) // returns elloHay orldway!
console.log(pigIt("Hello world, what a beautiful day.")) // returns elloHay orldway, hatway aay eautifulbay ayday.
console.log(pigIt("How are you? I am doing good!")) // returns owHay reaay ouyay? Iay maay oingday oodgay!
```

In this example, how do I check in one line, if "!","?","," or "." are included in the word?
Same problem with indexOf just below.

Thanks!

Comment: Put the characters you are looking for into an array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf then helps with the first part, and for the second, you can loop over that array, and then perform the string indexof check for each item.

Comment: You can also start with the second thing directly - check if `!` is contained _anywhere_ in the word, and then check whether the word length is 1 or not, to determine whether you want to push just the word, or do the slicing and add “ay” part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `some` and `includes` methods

```js
function pigIt(str) {
  const words = str.split(" ");
  const result = [];
  for (let word of words) {
    if (["!", "?", ".", ","].some((char) => word.includes(char))) {
      word.length > 1
        ? result.push(
            word.slice(1, word.length - 1) +
              word[0] +
              "ay" +
              word[word.length - 1]
          )
        : result.push(word);
    } else {
      result.push(word.slice(1) + word[0] + "ay");
    }
  }
  return result.join(" ");
}

console.log(pigIt("Hello world")); // returns elloHay orldway
console.log(pigIt("Hello world !")); // returns elloHay orldway!
console.log(pigIt("Hello world, what a beautiful day.")); // returns elloHay orldway, hatway aay eautifulbay ayday.
console.log(pigIt("How are you? I am doing good!")); // returns owHay reaay ouyay? Iay maay oingday oodgay!
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.match` and use regular expression:

```
if (word.match(/[!?,.]/) {
    result.push(word)
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `RegExp.prototype.test()` returning `true` or `false` be a better option to answer the question *'...how do I check .. if  ...are included'*?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Regex` to filter out the special characters as below

```js
const input = [
 "Hello world", // returns elloHay orldway
 "Hello world !", // returns elloHay orldway !
 "Hello world, what a beautiful day.", // returns elloHay orldway, hatway aay eautifulbay ayday.
 "How are you? I am doing good!" // // returns owHay reaay ouyay? Iay maay oingday oodgay!
];

const result = input.map(item => item.split(/\s+/).map(word => {
    const matchedVal = word.match(/[,.!?]$/g);
    return matchedVal ? 
      word.length === 1 ? word :
      `${word.substring(1, word.length - 1)}${word.charAt(0)}ay${matchedVal[0]}` : `${word.substring(1)}${word.charAt(0)}ay`
}).join(" "));

console.log(result);
```